How to change variable inside Inspector app.config w/ Sanic
I've started to learn Odoo, but the error is baffling me. I've asking questions to ChatGPT and Gemini why the problem occurs, but every time I checked, the code are the same. I don't know why the problem occurs. It happens after I started the Superuser on Odoo 14. I've followed the tutorial from here: https://tutorialopenerp.wordpress.com/2021/08/09/odoo-14-technical-documentation-part-3/
The errors from server side's Odoo are like this
Error:
`Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 652, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "D:\Odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 317, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
KeyError: 'training.course'`

I don't know how to identify it.
Can any developers help me finding it out. Thanks!
Here are the source code:
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/zaqQ1QQr#link
Help me find out why the problem occurs and how I can fix it.

The question needs debugging details. I know there is a file "attached" but that file could be deleted any day, so that later on the question will become useless.

Erroneous security file is the cause of the issue.
An example for how to set up appropriate security for file for custom models is given below.
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_training_course,access.training.course,model_training_course,base.group_user,1,1,1,1

